# Android Studio - Only install APK

Tags: android, android-studio, deployment, apk

I am currently working on a "stand alone" service. I want this service to be accessible by any application that may want to use it. For that I have created an android project that only contains that service, without any Activity. I'm not sure whether this is the right way to acheive my goal, but I'm unfamiliar with Android.

My problem is, how do I only deploy the .apk to the (physical) device ? In order to start the service, i'm using `adb shell` and then `am startservice ...`, but I first need to install that service on the device. How do I do that ? The only options I see are meant to run/debug the application (and thus automatically deploy it), but I can't do that since it's a service. Thank you.

Comment: Create android library with service and attach to any application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open terminal in project's root folder and type:

```
gradlew.bat installDebug
```

for Windows or:

```
./gradlew installDebug
```

for Linux

Edit: 
You can do it with UI, just click the "Gradle" tab on the right, find "installDebug" in tasks and click it twice.

[image]

After that it will be default action performed on Shift+F10 (or clicking "Run" button).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been using adb install, which works, but using a command line everytime is really painful.

Comment: how to get the Shift+F10 back to old, default behavior?

Comment: @user2297550 you just have to pick the application's module from the dropdown.